# Flexslider. Start slider dinamically according to the clicked image

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I have a page with a foreach in header that show 5 first images of my flexslider. I want to start slider popup according to image clicked.

My HTLM is:

```
  <ul class="images">
      @foreach ($images as $image)
         <li class="bkg-cover" style="background-image: {{
          $image['url']}}">
             <a class="startSlide" title="View Photo"><span>View 
               Photo</span></a>
         </li>
     @endforeach
   </ul>
```

Then my script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

       //View Photos
      $('.images > li > a').on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $('.images-modal').show();
          var slider = $('#ImagesSlide').data('flexslider');
          slider.resize();
       });

      //FlexSlider
      $('#imagesSlide').flexslider({
          animation: "slide",
          useCSS: false,
          smoothHeight: false,
          pauseOnHover: false,
          controlNav: false,
          //Integer: The slide that the slider should start on
          startAt: 0, 
          prevText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
          nextText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'
      });   

  </script>
```

$image is bidimensinal array where:

```
         $image[]['url']
```

Contains URL of image

```
          $image[]['position']
```

Contains position image in slider

I know option startAt of flexslider (0 start on first image) but I want to take this integer value dinamically with jQuery. I have "startSlide" class but I dont know how get the click event...

I tried get rel attribute value:

```
 <ul class="images">
      @foreach ($images as $image)
         <li class="bkg-cover" style="background-image: {{
              $image['url']}}">
             <a class="startSlide" rel="$image['position]" title="View 
               Photo"><span>View 
               Photo</span></a>
         </li>
     @endforeach
   </ul>
```

And construct the slider like this:

```
   $('#property .property-images .info .button, #property .property-images 
         ul.images > li > a').on('click', function(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           $('.images-modal').show();
           var numberSlider = $('.startSlide').attr('rel').valueOf();
           var numSlider = parseInt(numberSlider);
           var slider = $('#propertyImagesSlide').flexslider({
               animation: "slide",
               useCSS: false,
               smoothHeight: false,
               pauseOnHover: false,
               controlNav: false,
               startAt: numSlider,
               prevText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
               nextText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'
           });
           //var slider = $('#propertyImagesSlide').data('flexslider');
           slider.resize();
       });
```

But always startAt first image

Best thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this solution worked for me.

HTML:

```
  <ul class="images">
       @foreach ($property->allImages() as $position => $image)
          <li class="bkg-cover" style="background-image: {{ $image['url'] }}">
             <a class="startSlide" rel="{{ $position }}" title="View Photo"> 
             <span>View Photo</span></a>
          </li>
       @endforeach
  </ul>


    $('a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.images-modal').show();
        var memberid = $(this).attr('rel').valueOf();
        var memberidNo = parseInt(memberid);
        var slider = $('#propertyImagesSlide').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            useCSS: false,
            smoothHeight: false,
            pauseOnHover: false,
            controlNav: false,
            startAt: memberidNo,
            prevText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
            nextText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'
             });
            slider.resize();
         });
```

This fiddle help me a lot: http://jsfiddle.net/We4GA/

Now the problem is when I close modal and open again, Slider instance is already created and slider dont open in that image. Any comment for this issue?